# Changing variables in realtime when debugging in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, testing

Using Eclipse, when debugging is it possible to change the value of variables during runtime of a project for testing purposes.

For example, say I have a method that returns the number 5 but for testing purposes i want to output 10 instead. This isn't the problem I'm facing its a little more complex but its just to get my idea across.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should be able to set a break-point, go into debug mode, open the variables views and here change the content of the variables.

[image]

Comment: For any other new Eclipse users: get variables view with Window -> Show View -> Variables

Comment: It says type doesn't match when trying to set Boolean. tried both true and new Boolean(true) and Boolean.TRUE both say Type Mismatch

Comment: @Jackie, I can expand my Boolean variable and change the `value` field from `true` to `false` in a dropdown menu. I can also right-click on the variable and enter a whole new expression for it, and entering `Boolean.FALSE` works fine for me. Post a new question, including a small program and version of Eclipse and a screen shot of your situation and I can help further.

Answer (score 21):

You can access variables through the [Variables view](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/variables/ref-variables_view.htm). There you can right click on any variable and select "[Change value ...](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/shared/ref-changevarvalue.htm)".

---

**Resources :**

- [standford.edu - eclipse guide](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs108/JavaTools/eclipse-guide/)
- [help.eclipse.org - change var value](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/shared/ref-changevarvalue.htm)

Answer (score 7):

... and you can do much, much more:-) Just to give you and idea.
You may change the code during debug which is hot swapped and is effectively changed (recompiled) in given debug session.
You may run given method run (e.g. after catching breakpoint) few times without rerunning debug -> use drop to frame feature on method stack.

Comment: this sounds interesting..could you explain what drop to frame is?

Comment: It reruns given method on the stack. So it is invoked as at the first time with same parameters. see it here http://www.vasanth.in/2004/06/08/eclipse-tip-rewind-during-debugging/

Answer (score 5):

After you have changed the code you have to save it (cntrl-S) to make it effective.
You will see your running application respond to the code-change after the cntrl-S

I hope this works for you. it took me some time to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Run your application in debug mode then go to variables window. select the parameter then change values according to your requirements. then save (ctrl+s). and go ahead with your changes.  Hope this will help.

If variables window is missing. then goto eclipse window->show views->variables