# Changing object fields on the fly while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering whether I can change object fields and in general variables on the fly while debugging a java application in Eclipse in order to speed up my testing.

thanks much.

Comment: Yes you can and apparently this has been asked before, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778217/changing-variables-in-realtime-when-debugging-in-eclipse)

Comment: Surely the fastest way to find out is to _try_ it?