# Change variable value eclipse in debug perspective at run time

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

it's a long time since I used Eclipse Helios, and I found some difficult in changing variable at run time during debug.

I have put a breakpoint, and when debugger stops there it shows the object I am looking for in the 'variable' panel, which appears when in debug perspective.

The value I am trying to change is a Boolean inside the object, however these are the unsuccessful tentatives I did:

1. Expanded the object, look for variable expanded it until it shows value, changed value to false: this results in changing all the boolean in the object
2. Add watch expression to the boolean variable, but then I wasn't able from there to find a way to change its value

don't know if it is relevant, the application I am debugging is running on an old jboss 5.1, and the debug itself is done by running jboss in debug mode, and connect trough eclipse with a debug configuration. All is installed on my localhost.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778217/changing-variables-in-realtime-when-debugging-in-eclipse

Answer (score 17):

Following steps worked for me:

1. Click on **Window** -> **Open Perspective** -> **Debug**
2. Click on Tab **Variables**.
3. **Right click the variable** for which you want to change the value and click on **Change Value**...
4. Set the Value as **`Boolean.TRUE`** in the dialogue and click Ok.

Answer (score 12):

You can change the value.

Right click on the variable add it to 'watch' and then while debugging go to 'Expressions View', there you can change value

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

when the breakpoint stops write the following code:

```
// yourObject.setBoolean(Boolean.TRUE);
```

now select the code and press Ctrl+Shift+I. Voila you are done.

Comment: This is the Inspect command. And it works on class variables as well as automatic ones. Worked for me perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Go to Variables window where you can see the values of the current object of the line. Now Say for example Item I is an object which has an attribute `itemSold` of Boolean type.

Item

`->itemSold`

You can change the value of this `Boolean` variable as follows:

Right click on the attribute itemSold, you will get an option of Change Value.
In that window, write as follows and press ok.

`Boolean b=true;`

`return b;`

Now once you press ok, the value of `itemSold` will update to true.
You can do something similar for getting false.

Answer (score 0):

Additional option is right click evaluate and than set your value

Answer (score 0):

Select that variable and press Ctrl + Shift + I to open Inspect View, then press the same keys combination to open Expression View.  You can change its value there.