# Java Eclipse evaluate expression

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Is it possible to evaluate a expression in Eclipse similar to IntelliJ. Where you can dynamically type code and the result will be displayed during debug?. I know it does something similar "Display" but you need to highlight code that has been written (so you cant write any new code unless you re-compile).

Perhaps there are plugins that i could use?. I have just started using eclipse

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a *Display* view as well that can do exactly what you want. Go to `Window > Show view > Display` (or Other... if the *Display view* is not there. In the *Display view*, you can type any code you want during debug (content assist is available). The current objects and variables are also available to use. After you wrote your code, you have to highlight it, right click and select `Execute` or hit `CTRL-U`. You may play around with the other possible actions as well.

Besides that, you can also write in the source code during debug and evaluate it using *Display* as you mentioned, if you have the source for the class you are debugging.

Comment: Also one can select "Display" option from context menu to see the result without actual execution.

Comment: Answer no longer valid for Eclipse Neon

Comment: Which part and why not?

Comment: I am sorry to say, but either I am doing something completely wrong or this feature is lightyears away from what IntelliJ offers...

Comment: Starting with Eclipse 4.8 (Photon) the display view is replaced by the 'Debug Shell'

Answer (score 10):

1 - Type your expression inside a method that you are debugging

2 - Select that code

3 - Press CTRL + SHIFT + I

4 - Eclipse will evaluate your expression and show the results in a floating window

Comment: "Press CTRL + SHIFT + I" this should be the correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can change variable values on the fly using the Debug perspective.
The top right corner of Eclipse should have the variables view from which you can select a variable name and change its value.  You can also set conditional breakpoints by selecting the breakpoints view in the top right corner of Eclipse.  Right-click on the breakpoint and select  breakpoint properties.  Check the conditional checkbox and write an expression that only when it evaluates as true does the program suspend during Debugging.

[Change Variable Values during Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778217/changing-variables-in-realtime-when-debugging-in-eclipse)

[Conditional Breakpoints](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint?)

Answer (score 1):

Although Display View works; There are two ways else to evaluate an expression.

1. In the context of the debugging session, we can write and run custom code to evaluate possibilities. This is done in the Debug Shell. For example, if we need to cross-check the correctness of the sqrt functionality, we could do it in the Debug Shell. On the code, Right-click -> Inspect to see the value.
2. You can select an expression then open Context Menu -> Inspect or press CTRL + Shift + I, during debugging, the result will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Select any expression in your code. Then right-click and select "Display" (or press the associated key-combination).

For completely new expressions, use the Display view. It's like a scrapbook for expressions. If the Display view is not visible, select `Window > Show view > Display` to add it. Then type any expression in the view, and do the same thing as for expressions in your code: select the expression, right-click and select "Display".

For expressions that you want to always see the value of, every time execution is halted, use the Expressions view instead.

Answer (score 0):

For people who might come here looking for a way to get the complete value when Eclipse shortens it in display view:

- You can add it to `Expressions` (Window -> Show View -> Other -> Debug -> Expressions)
- Add you expression
- After it is evaluated, right click -> `Select All` -> `Copy Expressions`

This copies both the expression and the complete result - was necessary in my case because result was a long json string and eclipse kept displaying a shortened version of it with three dots